# how to bind objects with `form:select` in Spring

Tags: spring-form

I have the following in my jsp:

```
                     <form:select path="category">  
                         <form:options items="${categories}"  itemValue="categoryId" itemLabel="categoryName"/>
                     </form:select>
```

I want `itemValue` to be the category object and not a property. I tried to omit 'itemValue' thinking it would default to the object, but I guess that will happen only if I omit both `itemValue` and `itemLable`?

So what is the best way to do this?